# Avoid dangling processes for pm2 cron jobs

Tags: node.js, deployment, pm2

I'm using pm2 to define various jobs that need to be run on a regular basis. Here's an example:

```
{
  "name": "recalc-score",
  "script": "dist/jobs/recalc-score.js",
  "cron_restart": "5 0 * * *",
  "env": {
    "NODE_ENV": "production"
  }
},
```

The task is done in less than a second, yet if I call `ps aux` or `pm2 monit` I see that pm2 is keeping a process alive for each task. Consuming 40+MB of RAM each.

Is there a way to avoid this behaviour? I really like the ease of creating new jobs on the server by just updating the `ecosystem.json` so I really would like to stick with pm2, but sacrificing a significant amount of RAM for tasks that are run for a second once a day feels not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this seems to be somewhat blocked by this issue: https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/2487

But here's a solution that works just as nicely. I've created a single `worker.js` script which runs [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule). Here I've define all the cron tasks. This requires only one single process.